# UNIQUE constrains in Android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

If I put one of my columns in Android SQLite database

```
"passed BOOLEAN NULL UNIQUE"
```

The `UNIQUE` constrain will not allow me to put duplicates of even NULL values? But if I do not set the values in the column, it is default to be null, so is this against the rule? Is there other way I could work around with the `UNIQUE` constrain? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, only one null value is allowed per column.

As per this [link](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q26) no work around except rearchitecting tables.

Comment: That's not entirely correct - 
"For the purposes of UNIQUE constraints, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs."
Which means that more than one NULL value is allowed per column.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#uniqueconst

Comment: @NatiDykstein: You are correct in definition, if I am not wrong SQLite re-interpreted it in own terms which is what  link in my answer points to.

Comment: I'm not sure to what you refer in re-interpreted but from my direct experience with Android's SQLite,it allows multiple NULL values in UNIQUE columns.

Comment: 1) Definition of UNIQUE "For each UNIQUE constraint on the table, each row must contain a unique combination of values in the columns identified by the UNIQUE constraint. For the purposes of UNIQUE constraints, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs." 2) Refer link in my answer "The SQL standard requires that a UNIQUE constraint be enforced even if one or more of the columns in the constraint are NULL, but SQLite does not do this.", which is why it is working for you.